# How to fix this LaTeX Error: "Environment example undefined"?

Tags: environments, templates

The compiler is showing "LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined", which is 100% reproducible [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbrcmcffsgbz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Empirical distribution}
\author{Jane Doe}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{My first section}
\begin{example}
\xi_n = [x_1 \dots x_n]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

## error message

> LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined.
>
> You have created an environment (using \begin{…} and \end{…} commands) which is not recognized. Make sure you have included the required package for that environment in your preamble, and that the environment is spelled correctly.

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \begin{example}
                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

I wrote this by using the template that the compiler provided. Why the compiler does not its own template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing any screenshot for `Example` style, so I've defined my own, and the codings are :

```
\newenvironment{example}{\bgroup\par\noindent\textbf{Example}\par%
\[}{\]\egroup}
```

Please paste the above codings after `\begin{document}` and then try...

Comment: Thanks a lot! The error is gone. The `Example` style is provided by the online compiler, I don't know how to get the definition of this style.

Comment: Glad to hear that the error got solved...

Comment: I am getting `Environment Verbatim undefined.` even though `\begin{Verbatim}` is inside  `\begin{document}`

Comment: Correct code is `\begin{verbatim}` not `Verbatim`

Comment: If still the error exists, then please provide your code, what you tried for